# DB:raw no me funciona con mi sentencia sql en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, lumen

Estoy haciendo una consulta sql, considero que no es tan sencilla así que descarte el uso de eloquent al principio, el problema es que las ejecuciones con DB::raw me arrojan un arreglo vacío (aunque incluso eloquent tambien), lo cual no es correcto ya que he ejecutado la sentencia en editores y si me arroja valores (los correctos), estoy utilizando mysql y Lumen.

Acá la sentencia sql:

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE 
(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) 
AND
(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 23 HOUR));
```

Aca lo que hago en Laravel, esta sentencia me arroja un arreglo vacío:

```
$recordatorio = DB::select("SELECT * FROM dates WHERE 
        (CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) 
        AND
        (CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))"
    );
```

Tambien he intentado:

```
$recordatorio = DB::table('dates')
        ->whereRaw("(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))")
        ->whereRaw("(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))");
```

con esta ultima sentencia, ejecuto enseguida:

```
$this->info($recordatorio->toSql());
```

y esa ultima sentencia me arroja por consola:

```
select * from `dates` where (CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) and (CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))
```

Al ejecutar esta ultima sentencia en un editor como phpmyadmin o dbeaver funciona, pero si ejecuto `$recordatorio->get();` entonces me devuelve un arreglo vacío.

Se que toda la sentencia sql esta bien porque en crudo funciona bien, pero no la puedo trasladar a Lumen-Laravel.

Comment: ¿La conexión a la BD está bien en tu entorno Laravel? ¿Una consulta sencilla arroja datos?

Comment: Si tengo conexión con base de datos y las consultas funcionan bien.

Comment: Dinos qué código estás usando finalmente y que no funciona para partir de algo concreto. En la pregunta nos dices que has intentando de tal y tal forma, debes quedarte con un código para trabajar sobre él, ¿cuál es el estado actual del código?

Comment: la sentencia que tiene los whereRaw es la que estoy intentando mas ya que es la que esta en la documentación de Laravel actualmente, o bueno la que estoy viendo

Comment: Tienes que agregarle `get()` al final, como muestra la doc, algo así:  **`$recordatorio = DB::table('dates')
        ->whereRaw("(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))")
        ->whereRaw("(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(start_date, ' ', start_time)), DATETIME) >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))")->get();`**

Comment: yo le agrego el get en $recordatorio->get(); ... lo coloque en la explicación

Comment: ¿Y qué muestra en ese caso un `var_dump($recordatorio);`?